Error with 'markNeedsBuild' in syncfusion_flutter_charts After Flutter Upgrade
I'm using the Syncfusion Chart in my Flutter application, and everything was working fine until I upgraded Flutter to the latest version. Now, I'm encountering the following error during debugging:

Error (Xcode):
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-25.2.6/lib/src/charts/cartesian_chart.dart:1367:22:
Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class

I tried the following approaches to resolve the issue:
Cleaning the Flutter build: I ran flutter clean to remove any old build artifacts, followed by flutter pub get to fetch the latest dependencies. I expected this to resolve any potential build issues caused by cached files.
Updating the Syncfusion Chart package: I checked if there was a newer version of the syncfusion_flutter_charts package available and updated it accordingly. I expected that the latest version might have fixes for compatibility with the latest Flutter version.
Running flutter pub get: After upgrading Flutter, I ensured that all dependencies were properly updated by running flutter pub get. I expected this to sync all dependencies with their latest compatible versions.
Checking Flutter and Dart versions: I verified that my Flutter and Dart SDKs were up-to-date and compatible with the dependencies in my pubspec.yaml.
Despite these efforts, the error persists. I expected these steps to resolve any compatibility or caching issues that might be causing the markNeedsBuild method not to be found.

I am having same issue

check that answer

You can check this links:
Link1
Link2
Link3

I am also facing the same issue with the latest Flutter version 3.24.0
To solve this problem I have followed this :
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/element_widge
t.dart:117 ( Here 117 means line number )
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/base.dart:3317 ( Here 3317 means line number )
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/cartesian_chart.dart:1367 ( Here 1367 means line number )
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/core_tooltip.dart:168 ( Here 168 means line number )
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/core_legend.dart:452 ( Here 452 means line number )
You need to change markNeedsBuild to markNeedsLayout In this dart file.

I hope the problem will be solved.

You can add this to your pubspec.yaml file
syncfusion_flutter_charts:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Luvti/flutter-widgets
      path: packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts
      ref: 15e3c4a95e3cf2e2393755bf5aa11c0206ed6dea #flutter/3.24

credits goes to: Luvti

The problem occurs because the Flutter SDK has been upgraded to version 3.24.0, while the Syncfusion_flutter_charts package is currently compatible with Flutter SDK version 3.22.3.
They said they will release an updated version in mid-September.
So we need to use Flutter SDK version 3.22.3.
